# ANCOVA - Non-linearity of covariate

Tags: linear-model, assumptions, ancova, linearity

I have a dataset where I calculated genetic distances between populations of some animals (a continuous variable). I want to know if these differences are explained by physical or/and ecological characteristics of the organisms. My explanatory variables are type of dispersal (categoric), temperature regulation (categoric), geographic distribution (continuous) and body length (continuous).

I considered ANCOVA as the best choice to analyze my data, but I have some doubts about the assumptions. I made a log transformation to normalize my data and fix the variance (and it works perfectly), but when I check the linearity of the covariates with my response variable, they are not significant. So my question is: Should I remove the covariates and make an ANOVA? (It doesn't sound correct for me, but I'm not sure)

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to CV! Are you asking whether removing insignificant predictors is a good idea? In that case, the answer is probably no, because that would be stepwise regression. Also, an explanatory not being significant does not prove that its relationship with the response variable is non-linear, but even if it were, there are other things you could consider (e.g. transformation). It would be easier to advice if you edit your question to include some more information about your data and research question.